# Equivalent to "ps -p"

Tags: ps, top, busybox

I'm using a board without the full `ps` command installed.
What I need is `ps -p` equivalent (something that sets `$?` if a specific PID is found or not).

Is there a way to accomplish this with another command (like top)?

```bash
## wannabe_watchdog.sh

MY_EXE="$1"
_pid=-1

while test 1 -eq 1 
do
## this ps -p isn't available on the busybox
ps -p ${_pid}
if test $? -eq 0
then
    echo "executing"
    sleep 10
else
    echo "not executing"
    ./${MY_EXE} &
    sleep 1 
    agent_pid=$(cat /var/run/my_pidfile.pid)
    
    echo "waiting for ${_pid}"
    #wait function sometimes isn't blocking (and I never figured out exactly when)
    wait ${_pid}
    echo "${_pid} is dead - restarting"
fi

done
```

Comment: On Linux and _some_ other Unices: `test -d /proc/$pid`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic way of checking whether a process exists for a given pid is [to send it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) [“signal” 0](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html):

```
kill -0 "${_pid}"
```

This will exit with code 0 if the process exists, 1 otherwise, and will not affect the running process in any way.

The `kill` process needs to have sufficient permissions to send signals to the target process (*i.e.* be run by the same user as the target process, or root, or have equivalent privileges).

Comment: Will `kill` return an error if your user is not allowed to send signals to that process?

Comment: @SottoVoce that’s a good point, yes, it will return an error if the user isn’t allowed to send signals to the process.